# Colorbox Iframe Manual Call?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

is it possible to open a colorbox iframe by clicking on a div like so?

```
<div class="somediv" onclick="$.colorbox({href:'preview.html'});">
```

This opens an Ajax modal, however I would like to open an iframe without having to store the url outside this div.

Is that possible?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="somediv" onclick="$.colorbox({href:'preview.html', iframe:true, width:'90%', height:'90%'});">
```